# toString(format) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got this statement in javascript:

```
<script>
alert((444).toString(16));
</script>
```

Why is the output 1bc ? I tried in .net it gives 16, i don't understand can someone help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output 1bc is 444 in base 16 ([hexidecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)). In other words, the [Number.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method in JavaScript takes an optional base (radix) for the output conversion. In contrast, C#'s [Int32.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx) method takes a format string.

If you want format strings in JavaScript, you can look at the answers for the question [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610415/1427124) (the answer I linked to suggests a JS library providing an sprintf function).

Comment: Thank you DaeWen just figured it out.

Comment: Convert.ToString(444, 16) in .net

Comment: You could probably also do something like (444).ToString("x") in .NET (I think that's how you'd call it based off [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)). Also, you can click the green checkmark to accept my answer if it answered your question. :)